# Why does this code not work? The images show up as the no image symbols

Tags: html, image

This code shows up as the no info symbols. I have all the image files.

```
<a href='someurl'>
  <img src='someImage<img src="Buttonplay.gif" width="1152" height="648" alt="Play" title="Play Button" border="0" align="middle" />' />
</a>
```

This code shows up as the no info symbols. I have all the image files.

Comment: There is not enough information here.

Comment: first part of the markup is broken

Comment: @ArunPJohny It still does not work. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @jzisawesome: In the future, format code using the `{}` button or Ctrl-K, or by adding four spaces at the beginning of each line. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Your HTML is completely hosed.  What did you expect?  You can't just randomly jam tags into other tags.

Comment: @jzisawesome: An example would be something like this: `<img src="Buttonplay.gif" width="1152" height="648" alt="Play" title="Play Button" border="0" align="middle" />`  You *clearly* have some sort of copy/paste error in your HTML, where you've added an `img` tag randomly in the middle of another `img` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is really the HTML and not a mistake in entering the example, then your issue is because the `<img/>` is not well-formed. You have an image element nested inside of the image src attribute.

```
<img src='someImage<img src="Buttonplay.gif" width="1152" height="648" 
 alt="Play" title="Play Button" border="0" align="middle" />' />
```

should be:

```
<img src="Buttonplay.gif" width="1152" height="648" 
 alt="Play" title="Play Button" border="0" align="middle" />
```